# Convex sets via fixed point equations

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-geometry, convex-polytopes, fixed-point-theorems

I have an equation of the general form
$$ X = S \cup T X $$
where $S \subset \mathbb R^n$ is a convex polytope (given by its bounding hyperplanes), $T\colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ is a linear map, and the largest $X \subset \mathbb R^n$ must be found.

Is there an easy way to solve this and similar problems?

Comment: Conditions on $T$ are in order; for instance, from the equation,  the  existence of $X$  (a bounded n-dimensional  body) implies that $T$ maps a bounded  nonempty open   set  into itself , which I think implies the spectral radius of $T$ is  less than or equal to $1$. If $T$  has spectral radius  less than $1$ then  $X\mapsto S\cup TX$ is a contraction  wrto the Hausdorff distance and has  a unique  fix point among closed  bounded sets.

Comment: Do you mean the smallest $X$?

Comment: No, but I meant $\cap$ instead of $\cup$. Sorry.

Comment: @rimu : One should not change the question so as to invalidate an existing answer. So, please roll back your edit, and then you can post a new question -- after re-reading it very carefully, so as not to waste other users' time.

Comment: Done. (O rather undone...)

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand\R{\Bbb R}$If $X=S\cup T(X)$, then
$$T(X)=T(S)\cup T^2(X),\quad X=S\cup T(S)\cup T^2(X), \ldots, \\ 
X=S\cup T(S)\cup\cdots\cup T^{n-1}(S)\cup T^n(X) \\ 
\subseteq Y:=S\cup T(S)\cup\cdots\cup T^{n-1}(S)\cup T^n(\R^n).$$
On the other hand, $Y=S\cup T(Y)$, since $T^{n+1}(\R^n)=T^n(\R^n)$.

So, the largest $X$ such that $X=S\cup T(X)$ is $Y$.

In particular, if $S$ is a singleton set $\{s\}$, then the largest $X$ such that $X=S\cup T(X)$ is
$$\{s,Ts,\dots,T^{n-1}s\}\cup T^n(\R^n).$$
If e.g. $n=3$, $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ is a basis of $\R^3$, $S=\{e_1\}$, $Te_1=e_2$, $Te_2=e_3$, and $Te_3=e_3$, then the largest $X$ such that $X=S\cup T(X)$ is
$$\{e_1,e_2\}\cup\R e_3.$$